# Unittest for IOError exception handling

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, ioerror

Given this code:

```
 try:
        #do something
 except IOError as message:
        logging.error(message)
        raise message
```

I want to test the exception handling part in order to have full coverage.
In the unittest I've tried with:

```
        with patch(new=Mock(side_effect=IOError(errno.EIO))):
            self.assertRaises(IOError)
```

but it doesnt work.
Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need to start the Mock so that the `side_effect`starts, for example the following:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        mock = m.Mock()
        mock.side_effect = Exception("Big badaboum")
        self.assertRaises(Exception, mock)
```

`self.assertRaises` can take a callable as second argument, making it equivalent to:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        mock = m.Mock()
        mock.side_effect = Exception("Big badaboum")
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            mock()
```

And if you want to use it in a test with patch, you can do the following:

```
import unittest.mock as m
import unittest

def raise_error():
    try:
        print("Hello") #placeholder for the try clause
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) #placeholder for the exceptclause

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @m.patch("__main__.raise_error", side_effect=Exception("Big badaboum")) #replace  __main__ by the name of the module with your function
    def test(self, mock):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            mock()

unittest.main()
```

**Edit**: And to test the raise of an error inside an except block you need to mock a function call inside the try block you wrote, for instance:

```
import unittest.mock as m
import unittest

def do_sthing():
    print("Hello")

def raise_error():
    try:
        do_sthing() #this call can be mocked to raise an IOError
    except IOError as e:
        print(e.strerror)
        raise ValueError("Another one")

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        with m.patch("__main__.do_sthing", side_effect=IOError("IOError")):
            self.assertRaises(ValueError, raise_error)


unittest.main()
```

You can use the decorator syntax as well (just putting the test above rewritten to spare some CPU cycle):

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @m.patch("__main__.do_sthing",side_effect=IOError("IOError"))
    def test(self, mock):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, raise_error)
```

Comment: Hi asettouf, thanks for your answr. I tried it and although seemingly the test is passed, the code coverage shows that both try and except blocks are not tested. I think im missing something..

Comment: @Giuseppe "The code coverage", which kind? Also do you have a test for when an exception is not raised?

Comment: So far i tested when the exception was not raised with: self.assertRaises(IOError, myClass.myFunction). It works, but of course it fails because since it is dummy, no exceptions are raised. Now I've been required to have a full coverage and test also the except block. For doing this I would need to simulate an IOError

Comment: hanks, but how do I simulate an IOError in the mock?

Comment: @Giuseppe My bad, my previous comment might have been confusing, what you want to do is mock a call inside your try block to raise an `IOError`, and then `self.assertRaises(SomeException, call)`. I edited my post for more clarity

Comment: Thank you it works! Just a thing that is not totally clear at the moment, why raise ValueError("Another one") and not raise IOError?

Comment: @Giuseppe That was a random choice for the purpose of the example. We can replace it with `IOError` and obtain the same result